# System.Collections.Immutable reference to System.Runtime and FxCop/metrics

Tags: c#, metrics, immutable-collections

On `Windows 7` with `.NET 4.5.2` installed, I create a new ClassLibrary project targetting .NET 4.5.2.

I want to calculate the code metrics for that assembly by launching the `metrics.exe` that is shipped with `FxCop` with Visual Studio 2013 located in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\`.

Everything works fine.

I then nuget `System.Collections.Immutable v1.1.37`.

I can see in the references that only System.Collections.Immutable is referenced since the other dependencies (`System.Runtime`, `System.Collections`, `System.Diagnotics.Debug` etc.) are found (I suppose in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades\`)

I create a dummy method that creates a dummy ImmutableArray `var foo = new List<int>().ToImmutableArray();`

Everything compiles and works just fine.

I relaunch the metrics computation.

I have the following error:

> metrics.exe /f:c:\dev\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll /o:toto.xml
>
> error : CA0055 : Could not load file:
>   'c:\dev\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll'.

If I perform the same command on the `System.Immutable.Collections` assembly, I have the following error:

> Calculating metrics for file 'c:\dev\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'.
>   Could not locate the framework assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Now, if I copy the `System.Runtime` file located in `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\` in the output directory, calculating the code metrics on `ClassLibrary1.dll` works fine. But if I copy the version that is in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades\`, if fails again.

When debugging another library using Immutable in a web application, I can see the following in the "Loaded modules":

> System.Runtime.dll C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll Yes No  Skipped loading symbols.        544 4.06.1055.0 06/11/2015 03:49    000007FED10D0000-000007FED10D9000   [15760] w3wp.exe    [4] /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/WebSite-2-131026947404276669

All of this makes me think that System.Collections.Immutable uses the version of System.Runtime that is in `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`

So I thought, "let's add an explicit reference to that assembly." If I do, I got the following compilation error:

> error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Runtime.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades\System.Runtime.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

There something somewhere that is wrong and I can't pinpoint it.

I worked around the error by using the `/ignoreinvalidtargets` for `metrics.exe`.

Does anyone have a club about the real error?

(I also tried targetting .NET Framework 4 and adding references to all the dependant assemblies from `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\` with CopyLocal = true. It works, despite the following warning:

> Some NuGet packages were installed using a target framework different from the current target framework and may need to be reinstalled. Visit http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages for more information.  Packages affected: System.Collections, System.Collections.Immutable, System.Diagnostics.Debug, System.Globalization, System.Linq, System.Resources.ResourceManager, System.Runtime, System.Runtime.Extensions, System.Threading

)

Thanks.

Comment: You are digging yourself a pretty deep hole, you don't really understand the difference between reference assemblies and runtime assemblies.  Immutable has a lot of them since it is used on so many exotic platforms.  Focus only on the first error, nobody can guess why it can't load ClassLibrary1.dll.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution, show the trace you get if you don't understand what it means.

Comment: The issue is reproductible, as all the products used are listed, so people can figure out why it doesn't work. The culprit seems to be `metrics` that performs a static analysis of the assembly but can't find the correct dependencies of `System.Collections.Immutable` (except after I've copied locally the required assembly). `fuslogwv` shows no binding error.

Comment: That must be the reason you get so many answers.  Make fuslogvw.exe work, you need it.  Log all binds to ensure it is functional.

Comment: `fuslogvw.exe` works: by logging all binds, I have entries listed. If I compare the entries before (=> error) and after (=> success) copying `System.Runtime` in the folder, the only difference is that two less assemblies are bound in the latter case: `mscorlib.resources, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=fr, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089` and `Microsoft.Cci.resources, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=fr-FR, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`, nothing significant.
Neither my assembly nor `System.Collections.Immutable` nor `System.Runtime` appear in the entries.

Comment: Never mind, Visual Studio Code Metrics Powertool for Visual Studio 2015 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48213) works just fine when the aforementioned version would fail. That solves my issue.